# setprecision does not show digits

Tags: c++, floating-point, formatting

I have the following function fragments:

```
bool A_AbstractTester_Actor::Equals( int lineNumber, T_String valueText, double value, T_String expectedText, double expected, double accuracy )
{
    ...
    v_FailedText << std::setprecision(8) << "\nLine " << lineNumber  
     << ": EQUALS_DOUBLE FAILED, Value '" << valueText << "' (" << value 
     << "), Expected '" << expectedText << "' (" << expected << ")\n";
```

Later I print v_FailedText and the result is:

```
Line 242: EQUALS_DOUBLE_FAILED, Value 'step' (0), Expected '1.0' (1)
```

What I expected was :

```
Line 242: EQUALS_DOUBLE_FAILED, Value 'step' (0.00000000), Expected '1.0' (1.00000000)
```

Comment: If memory serves some of those manipulator calls are extremely ephemeral.  Does it still not work if you do the setprecision manipulator *just before* you print the floating point value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [std::fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) manipulator.

```
bool A_AbstractTester_Actor::Equals( int lineNumber, T_String valueText, double value, T_String expectedText, double expected, double accuracy )
{
    ...
    v_FailedText << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) "\nLine " << lineNumber  
     << ": EQUALS_DOUBLE FAILED, Value '" << valueText << "' (" << value 
     << "), Expected '" << expectedText << "' (" << expected << ")\n";
```